# Gradle Javadoc SNAPSHOT version

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I've got a Gradle task like:

```
task generateGHPagesDocs(type: Javadoc, dependsOn: assemble) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compile
    destinationDir = file('gh-pages/javadoc/')
    options.links = [ 'https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/' ]
}
```

and a `gradle.properties` like:

```
group=com.xyz
version=1.0.1
```

When running `./gradlew generatedGHPagesDoc`, the Javadocs say `<project name> 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT API`. This is strange, as there's no `SNAPSHOT` in the `version`.

Why is this, and how can I eliminate the `-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Is there also no `version` in `build.gradle` itself? Also please `grep` files searching for _snapshot_ string.

Comment: No version in `build.gradle`, and no `SNAPSHOT` anywhere except in the generated Javadocs.